# AJAX POST and RESTFul Web Services not working on IE 11

Tags: java, ajax, constructor

I have an `AJAX`  call to a `JAVA POJO` as follows -

```
    $.ajax({
            url:'./webapi/input/approve',
            type: 'PUT',
            data:jsonobj,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(!data){
                    alert("Invalid");
                }
                var values = JSON.stringify(data);
                alert(values);
            },
            error:function(xhr,textstatus,errorthrown){
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                alert(textstatus);
                alert(errorthrown);
            }
        },'json');
```

The corresponding `Constructor` in the `Java Pojo` that I have is as follows -

```
    public Input(String LR, double ECH,
            double CSH,String App) {
        this();
            lr = LR;
            ech = ECH;
            csh = CSH;
            app = App;
        }
```

In addition to this, I also have another `Parameterised and Default Constructor` in the same class. The issue that I am facing is that when I run my `.jsp` page, This `parameterised constructor` above should get called. However, When I run the same, the desired `constructor` does not get called. **Please note** that I am running `Internet Explorer v 11`. Also **note** that when I run the same on `Chrome`, I get the desired output. 
Help much appreciated!